# Generating serie of numbers and letters

Tags: php, function, random, numbers

I want to generate a serie of numbers from 1 to 5, I wrote the following code

```
<?php
   $tag = range(1,5);
   echo "Numbers : ".implode(" - F",$tag)."<br>";
?>
```

I expect to get this result :

```
F1 - F2 - F3 - F4 - F5
```

But I am getting that instead :

```
1 - F2 - F3 - F4 - F5
```

What should I modify to get the wanted result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the character to each resulting element:

```
echo "Numbers : " . implode(' - ', array_map(function($v) { 
     return 'F' . $v; 
}, range(1,5)));
```

Comment: I don't know enough about Pagepeed, but which method is faster? `array_map` or simply `"F" . $tag`?

Comment: @KuebelElch15 `'F' . $tag` won't work, as you are trying string concatenation on an array that can't be expressed as a string. It doesn't iterate the elements. You'll get something like `FArray`. You could do it with `foreach`, and in that case, it'll probably be faster, as there are less function calls involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use implode you need to add the "F" before the implode.

```
$tag = range(1,5);
echo "Numbers : F".implode(" - F", $tag)."<br>";
```

Output:

```
Numbers : F1 - F2 - F3 - F4 - F5<br>
```

https://3v4l.org/kPAHT

Comment: not relevant as I will use href for each of elements later

Comment: There is nothing in your question saying anything about it a link. You should have included that in your question. My answer does what your question says, so how can it not be relevant? If you want answers to something that your question is not, then it's your question that is irrelevant and not useful.